# Firebase Crash: how to remove on iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I want to disable Firebase Crash Reporting on iOS, as I am already using Crashlytics (through Fabric).

I removed `pod 'Firebase/Crash'` fom my Podfile, but when I compile the application, it gives me an error:

> Script-xxxxxxxxxxxxx.sh: line 3:
>   /myproject/Pods/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym: No such file or directory

how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried running `pod install` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the Run Script that was added to `Build Phases` when you originally [set up](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) Firebase Crash.

Comment: great! it fixed it!